# ListBox и Button соединение

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы при выборе в ListBox элемента,Button придавала значение переменной "n",как у названия элемента в Listbox 
Или сам Click по элементу придавал значение "n" как у названия элемента

Comment: Формулировка сложна для понимания. Полагаю вам достаточно будет написать обработчик события OnClick для Listbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно в обработчике события ListBox присвоить переменной n значение выбранного элемента. Для WinForms это может быть событие SelectedValueChange. Обработчик может выглядеть так:

```
private void ListBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    n = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

[Проект с примером WinForms](https://vk.com/doc331774140_449945296)

[Проект с примером WPF](https://vk.com/doc331774140_449945384)